# "Dual basis" generalizes to perfect pairing?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $V, W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$ with a nondegenerate pairing $V \times W \rightarrow F$ on them.  Then $w \mapsto \langle-,w \rangle$ is an isomorphism $\Phi$ of $W$ with the dual of $V$, and in particular, $V, W$ have the same dimension.

Given a basis $v_1, ... , v_n$ for $V$, there then exists a basis $w_1, ... , w_n$ of $W$ such that $\langle v_i, w_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.  Namely one defines $w_i = \Phi^{-1}(v_i^{\ast})$, where $v_i^{\ast}$ is the dual element of $v_i$ in $V^{\ast}$.

Now, assume we are working with free abelian groups rather than vector spaces.  Let $X, Y$ be finite rank free abelian groups with a perfect pairing $X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.  This means that $y \mapsto \langle -, y \rangle$ defines an isomorphism of $Y$ onto $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, and the same with $X$ and $Y$ reversed.

I assume we can say the same thing? To any basis $x_1, ... , x_n$ of $X$, there exists a basis $y_1, ... , y_n$ of $Y$ such that $\langle x_i, y_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.  The same argument as above seems to carry over.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. The crucial thing is the question whether the $y_i$ really generate $Y$. Because in the vector space case, you often use an dimension argument for this, which you cannot use over $\mathbb Z$. But we can help ourselves:

Let $y \in Y$ be arbitrary. Clearly $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $Y \otimes \mathbb Q$, thus we have $y = \sum \lambda_i y_i$ with $\lambda_i \in \mathbb Q$.

For an $j$ we obtain

$$\langle x_j, y \rangle = \sum \lambda_i \langle x_j,y_i \rangle = \lambda _j$$

, hence $\lambda_j \in \mathbb Z$ and we are done.